# ios - ZXing scanner from camera

Tags: ios, barcode, zxing, barcode-scanner

I'm a beginner at ios development and objective c (also new on stackoverflow). 
I'm trying to create a barcode and I've found this: https://github.com/TheLevelUp/ZXingObjC .

The only problem is that I want the scanner to be able to scan "live" the camera stream, how can I access it and use it as source for the scanner method?

p.s. i've also tried the example provided on github but it's not working, only opens the camera but nothing happens.

Thanks for the help

Comment: I use ZXingObjC in my own app and it works just fine. It scans using a "live" camera feed. What iOS device are you testing on? What version of iOS?

Comment: I'm using an ipad 2 with iOS 6.1..

Comment: That's the problem. The camera on the iPad 2 is terrible and rarely works with ZXing or ZBar. You need real good light on the barcode and only some barcodes will work. You will have much better luck with an iPhone 4 or newer or an iPad 3 or newer.

Comment: Thanks, I tried in different conditions and now works.. the only problem is that I don't have any feedback on the screen like an animation/border around the barcode scanned. 
It's not normal, is it?

Comment: Yes, it's normal. You may be able to add something. FYI - iOS 7 now has built-in support for barcode scanning. You may want to see if it works for your needs.

Comment: still facing this issue with iPhone xs